# Type declaration file not found in custom NPM package

Tags: typescript, npm

I wrote a NPM Package that contains type declarations for a legacy JS only NPM package.  This is all proprietary, so I can't publish it to public registries.  I'm trying to bring in the types package into a *different* types package that describes yet another legacy npm package.

Each types package declares modules using the notation:
`declare module "@company/legacy-package/sub-module"`

As such, I have the following project structure:

```
 - @company-a/project-a
    - node_modules
       - @company-a/project-b
```

`project-b` in the above example contains the following file structure:

```
 - index.d.ts
 - package-name.d.ts
   - `declare module "@company-b/package-name/module-name"`
```

Within project-a, attempting to import the module named in the above example, provides the "cannot find module" error:
`import { SomeStuff } from "@company-b/package-name/module-name"`

I made sure to include the typeRoots for project-a:

```
compilerOptions: {
   typeRoots: [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/@company-a/package-b"
   ]
}
```

I'm not sure what I've missed as I cannot get the types to be recognized for @company-b inside of the @company-a/package-a project.

When I included all the types directly into the project using the path: `src/@types/@company-b/package-name.d.ts` it worked just fine, but I'm having problem breaking that into its own npm package.

Comment: Don't use `declare module` wrappers for these packages.

Comment: @AluanHaddad That was the only way I could get it to work with the legacy packages.

Comment: Then something else is wrong with your approach. First, get it to work without `declare module` for a simple types package with no dependencies. Second, try it with dependencies between types packages. Also, typeroots should not contain the package folder names, but their parent folder.

Comment: Every example I can find shows how to do it with `declare module`.  I'm not sure I understand the alternative.

Comment: Not sure where you are looking, but the best place to find examples is at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I rewrote the typings for both packages, and included them in the packages themselves so I could avoid this problem altogether.